# What's the use of declaring an interface as a class member?

Tags: c#, interface

I cant really understand what happens and what's the use of declaring a class member as an interface. MSDN says that interface cannot be instantiated, so you can't say:

```
    IMovable i = new IMovable();
```

The reason you can't do this is pretty straight forward. But what's the use of declaring, for example:

```
  protected static IMovable i;
```

What does i represent in this case? What's the use of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to store a reference to an object implementing that interface, but you don't care what kind of object it is, only that it implements that interface.

Answer (score 3):

Because you will write your code so that it can use **any** implementation of `IMovable`, rather than just that one.

This allows you to build [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) code.

Answer (score 2):

The member `i` can represent any object the implements `IMovable`, that's why it's useful. You can assign different objects to `i` and have specific behavior depending on the object.

Answer (score 1):

That **interface member** will be assigned to an **instance** of a **class** *implementing the interface* by *someone* - either a DI framework or by custom code. Otherwise, yes, would be no point.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is kind of Abstraction (Contract) and cannot be instantiate. But if you implement your in your class then your:

```
interface IMovable {
  void DoStuff();
}

class ImplementinIMovableClass : IMovable {
  void DoStuff() { .. }
}

protected static IMovable i = new ImplementinIMovableClass();
```

Variable `i` only has property/method defined in that interface. In that case it is method `DoStuff();`

With Interface approach you can think of use **DependencyInjection** to reduce your code cupling.

Answer (score 1):

As many other answers have already pointed out, the `i` member variable can point to any implementation of `IMovable`.

This is not only a great benefit in terms of flexibility, but it is one way to realize the OO principle of [Polymorphism](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=polymorphism%20wiki&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism&ei=Zp6uTs-KG87KtAbItIkE&usg=AFQjCNEYQDZxbMI4RyzrALNBX6jwKnu8Hw&sig2=nb_fp7sT0doo57zNXgkpOg&cad=rja).

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces and abstract classes are very similar, though abstract classes may be easier to understand in the real world.

Something like "vehicle" would be an abstract class; something like "2010 Toyota Prius Hatchback" would be a concrete class.  It is possible to have, or to drive, either of the above.  On the other hand, one wouldn't buy a "vehicle" as such--one would buy a particular type of vehicle.  In real life, a person might hypothetically ask someone to buy him a vehicle, without specifying any particular kind, but in most programming languages a compiler in such a situation would want to know what sort.

The code which actually creates an object will have to know what type of object it's creating, but in many cases code will be given objects which have been created by other code.  Code which uses an abstract class or interface to specify what it's expecting from other code will be usable with other code that creates any class which derives from that abstract class or implements that interface.